# freemaker #list to loop only 10 items

Tags: list, freemarker

I have list which size may be less or greater than 10.

Current statement:

> <#list listValues as currentitem>

But I need to loop only 10 items of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a partial list using indices.

```
<#list listValues[0..*10] as currentItem>
```

The `*` will make sure you do not get index-out-of-bound errors (requires FreeMarker 2.3.21 or higher), since it will slice out up to 10 items, or less.

Comment: Note that you can also just directly issue `<#list listValues[0..*10] as currentitem>` - no need to `#assign`.